# How to show data value inside select box using jquery?

Tags: jquery

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#where_to_go").autocomplete({
            source: "search_city.php",
            select: function (event, ui) 
            {
                item_val =  ui.item.value;
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{"item_val":item_val},
                    url:"get-city.php",
                    success:function(data){
                        //alert(data);
                        ("#hotel_name").html(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

get-city.php

```
<?php 
include("dbase.php");
    $item_val = $_POST['item_val'];
?>
<select name="hotel_name" id="hotel_name">
    <option value="">Select Hotel</option>
    <?php
        $sql = "select hotel_name from hotel where city = '".$item_val."' or state = '".$item_val."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value='".$row['hotel_name']."'>".$row['hotel_name']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

In this code I have an autocomplete text box which work fine and when I select any value from autocomplete and use `alert(data)` then value are alert but using `$("#hotel_name").html(data)` it show nothing inside the select box. I don't know  why? So, how can I fix this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: does your code append data in the select box? please check and also please add the ajax response in your question.

Comment: use "$" befor ("#hotel_name").html(data)

Comment: Ohh no sorry I forgot "$" thanx @CananauCristian now its working.